# How do I write customized unit tests in R?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, tinytest

I am using the tinytest package for unit testing and wanted to modify some of the tests which did not work out. To boil down the problem I give the following example. I define a new function

```r
expect_equal_new <- function(a,b){expect_equal(a,b)}
```

If I put `expect_equal_new` and `expect_equal` in a test file and run `test_all()` from the tinytest package, only the result of `expect_equal` appears in the summary. 
Why is that the case? Is there a way that `test_all()` also finds `expect_equal_new`?